# How to present Xib with animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, xib, uianimation

I have a custom view (xib) and I am presenting this xib on a button click. The xib is presented without any issue.But, I couldnt present it with some animation.
Here is what I have tried:

```
// Instantiate the nib content without any reference to it.
NSArray *nibContents = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomView" owner:nil options:nil];

// Find the view among nib contents (not too hard assuming there is only one view in it).
UIView *plainView = [nibContents lastObject];

// Some hardcoded layout.
CGSize padding = (CGSize){ 12.0, 20.0 };
plainView.frame = (CGRect){padding.width, padding.height, plainView.frame.size};


// Add to the view hierarchy 
[self.tableView addSubview:plainView];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                     animations:
     ^{
         plainView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0f, 1.0f);

     }
     ];
```

Could anyone tell me how to present xib with animation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
plainView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.01f, 0.01f);
    // Add to the view hierarchy
    [self.tableView addSubview:plainView];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                     animations:
     ^{
         plainView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0f, 1.0f);

     }
     ];
```

Comment: this is scaling in. I need scaling out

Comment: Okay then add this line of code before you add plainView on  self.tableView as a subView    plainView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.01f, 0.01f);